# ASP:NET MVC 4 + MEF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mef

I created an application based on this article :
[mef-in-aspnet-mvc-4-and-webapi](http://kennytordeur.blogspot.be/2012/08/mef-in-aspnet-mvc-4-and-webapi.html)

It is a nice solution but how I can inject a dependency into an ActionFilter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for this problem.

First I had to create an own FilterProvider class:

```
 public class FilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer _compositionContainer;

    public FilterProvider(CompositionContainer compositionContainer)
    {
        _compositionContainer = compositionContainer;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<FilterAttribute> GetActionAttributes(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var attributes = base.GetActionAttributes(controllerContext,
                                              actionDescriptor);
        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            _compositionContainer.ComposeParts(attribute);
        }

        return attributes;
    }
}
```

And I had to add this class to FilterProviders collection:

```
 var provider = new FilterProvider(container);
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider);
```

using this I can inject any dependencies into a custom ActionFilter using import attribute.